# why is this JS confirm window not firing on form submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, confirm

**HTML:**

```
<form name="registerAppointment" method="post" action="formValidations/deleteValidate.php" onSubmit="return verifyForm()">
    <input type="hidden" name="userEmail" value="<?=$_SESSION['Mail']?>" />
    <input type="text" required name="studentId" size="20"/>
    <div class="pageFormResetSubmit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    function verifyForm() {
    if (document.addStudentForm.elements["studentId"].value.length == 9) {
        if (isNaN(document.addStudentForm.elements["studentId"].value)) {
            alert("Please enter only numbers for ID - no dashes or letters.");
            return false;
        }else{
            if( window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this student? This action CANNOT BE UNDONE.") ){
                studentIdField.setAttribute("value", document.addStudentForm.elements["studentId"].value);
                userForm.appendChild(studentIdField);
                document.body.appendChild(userForm);
                userForm.submit();
            }
        }
    } 
    else{
        alert("The ID must be 9 characters.");
        return false;
    }
};
```

When the `submit` button is hit, I want a confirmation dialog to appear, allowing them to confirm or cancel. For whatever reason, the confirm is not firing in the above code and the form processes as if it wasn't there.

Comment: Are you getting an alert? Which alert are you getting? Just a guess but `isNaN(document.addStudentForm.elements["studentId"].value)` should probably be `(document.addStudentForm.elements["studentId"].value != undefined)`

Comment: @RobM. They're trying to check to see if something is a number or not, so `isNaN` sorta accomplishes what they want. For example, `isNaN(undefined) == true` and `isNaN("123") == false`. Not a great use of the function (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) for some reasons why it's broken) but I don't think it's an error...

Comment: I see, `isNaN` is a terrible function, I mean considering NaN is a constant you would think "is NaN" would only be `=== NaN`. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @RobM. I am not getting any alert, the form is submitting just as if it wasn't there. Basically the first `if()` is checking for adequate length. then, it checks to make sure we're working with a number (if it isn't, the script returns `false`). Else, it is a 9 character long number, I want to `confirm` that they want to delete. If they click yes, submit the form. Otherwise cancel out of it like the `return false` line above.

Comment: Anyone? Figured this was an easy fix and I was just glancing over something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong form name:

`document.addStudentForm` should be `document.registerAppointment`

Comment: You are awesome. Don't know HOW I did not notice that. Long day of coding I guess. :) Thanks!